# Issue with using python exec() inside discord bot command

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I have basically identical code, one written in idle;
The command is a simple eval command so I can run python code from my bot. When I was testing this I learned how to do it in the idle so I just copied it over to the bot. For some reason the code in IDLE works yet in the bot it doesn't.

My Bot code:

````
try:
  cmd = "\n".join(f"    {i}" for i in command.splitlines())
  func = "def eval_cmd():\n"+cmd
  print(func)
  exec(func)
  embed = discord.Embed(title=" ", description="Code Evaluation: ", color=discord.Color.green())
  embed.add_field(name=":inbox_tray: Input", value="```{}```".format(command), inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name=":outbox_tray: Output", value="```{}```".format(eval_cmd()), inline=False)
  embed.set_author(name=message.author.name, icon_url=message.author.avatar_url)
  await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=embed)

except Exception as ex:
  template = "An exception of type {0} occurred. Arguments:\n{1!r}"
  error_message = template.format(type(ex).__name__, ex.args)
  await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.red(), description="You encountered an error: \n```{}```".format(error_message)))
````

My IDLE code:

```
command = '''
pi = 3.14
rad = 5
area = pi * rad**2
return area'''

cmd = "\n".join(f"  {i}" for i in command.splitlines())

func = "def eval_cmd(): "+cmd
print(func)

exec(func)
print(eval_cmd())
```

The code in IDLE works perfectly and the value of eval_cmd() is 78.5 - What it should be. Inside the bot when exec(func) is run it just returns None.

Is this an issue with discord? or am I missing something.

Comment: What commands did you try to test the eval from discord?

Comment: Instead of hardcoding indentation, remember you can use `;` to separate python statements

Comment: This was the code I was typing in discord:
`pi = 3.14
rad = 5
area = pi * rad**2
return area`
The same as the IDLE one.(with the line inbetween)